# Reading FromUri and FromBody at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, frombodyattribute

I have a new method in web api

```
[HttpPost]
public ApiResponse PushMessage( [FromUri] string x, [FromUri] string y, [FromBody] Request Request)
```

where request class is like

```
public class Request
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool TestingMode { get; set; }
}
```

I'm making a query to localhost/Pusher/PushMessage?x=foo&y=bar with PostBody:

```
{ Message: "foobar" , TestingMode:true }
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A post body is typically a URI string like this:

```
Message=foobar&TestingMode=true
```

You have to make sure that the HTTP header contains

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**EDIT**: Because it's still not working, I created a full example myself.
It prints the correct data.
I also used .NET 4.5 RC.

```
// server-side
public class ValuesController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    public string PushMessage([FromUri] string x, [FromUri] string y, [FromBody] Person p) {
        return p.ToString();
    }
}

public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Name + ": " + this.Age;
    }
}

// client-side
public class Program {
    private static readonly string URL = "http://localhost:6299/api/values/PushMessage?x=asd&y=qwe";

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("Name", "Johannes");
        data.Add("Age", "24");

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.UploadValuesCompleted += UploadValuesCompleted;
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Task t = client.UploadValuesTaskAsync(new Uri(URL), "POST", data);
        t.Wait();
    }

    private static void UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Result));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is true only if I use mvc structure. However this is web api so the binding is different than mvc. But thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ensure that the HTTP header contains `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: You are not able to post like plain text to web api mvc :S

Comment: Using this in your HTTP header Web API should understand that you have an url-encoded body. Could you please share your HTTP Header?

Comment: WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
            client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URL), "POST",  "ApplicationKey=asdasda&PusherKey=asdasdasd"); to test out your suggestion I have created a new method like         public ApiResponse PushMessage(string ApplicationKey, string PusherKey) but it didn't work either because binding has changed in RC. It gives internal server error.

Comment: Ohh i overlooked the fact that you make your request to localhost/Pusher/PushMessage, but WebAPI doesn't use the method name, it identifies the method by http method and params. So try to request localhost/Pusher.

Comment: if you give a special name to a method you may able to use it. This actually works public ApiResponse PushMessage(Request request){ } I could able to make a query.

Comment: I provided a full example (see updated answer). Maybe it can help you.

Comment: What if `x` and `y` are properties of the `Person` class? Can we get these properties `FromUri` and the other properties `FromBody`?

Comment: You mean send half of the Person in the URI and the other half in the body? I don't know, but I doubt it. Is there any use case for this?

Comment: Why should the content-type be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? I thought that was for requests with url params, and `multipart/form-data` should be used if there is any non-text body data. That said, I've tried both in this situation and only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works, I would just like to know the explanation.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is for _simple_ data that is sent in the body of the HTTP message and has the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`. As you correctly said `multipart/form-data` is for uploading blobs and requires a different format in the HTTP body (Google found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload) here).

Comment: This didn't work for my WebApi, my problem was that the body was missing prefix "=", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771631/782022

Answer (score 1):

The Web API uses naming regulations. The method for a post should be started with Post.

You should rename your PushMessage to method name PostMessage.

Also the web api defaulty listens (depending on your route) to 'api/values/Message' and not to Pusher/Pushmessage.

> [HttpPost] attribute is not required

Comment: The method for a post should be started with Post. : Not required

Comment: This answer is wrong. The method needs 'Post' in name only when there is no [HttpPost] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code to post json in request body:

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

Request request = new Request();
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost/Pusher/PushMessage?x=foo&y=bar", request).Result;

//check if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
var createResult = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourResultObject>().Result;
```