# Parameters are not getting passed from angular to Web API in the POST call

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Below is my angular and Web APi Code.In the post method null is getting passed instead of India
  Angular Code:

```
HWApp.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.SendData = function (Data)
      {
        $scope.whoo = Data;
        console.log(Data);

        $http({
         url: "api/call/firstCall",
         dataType: 'json',
         method: 'POST',
         data: "India",
          headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
           }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.whoo = response;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
           alert(error);
            });
        }
      }
    );
```

Web Api Controller

```
  public class CallController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string firstCallGet( )
        {
            return "Get";
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public string firstCall([FromBody] string a)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: I tried this also data: { data: 'India' } but same null is getting passed.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957248/how-to-send-post-in-angularjs-with-multiple-params/30957308#30957308

Comment: What I have understood so far for complex type **[FromUri]** is required but for the simple type we need **[FromBody]** and here I am using the simple one. In the articel above they are using the complex type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data parameter should be JSON object.

`data :{country : "India" }`

Define a model class to automatically deserialze into.

`Public class CountryViewModel{
  Public string Country{get; set;} 
}`

Web Api controller should be as follows

`public class CallController : ApiController
{
      [HttpPost]
      public string FirstCall( CountryViewModel in)
      {
           return in.Country;
      }
}`

Comment: Property mismatch in CountryViewModel, json returns `country` and model expects `Country`.

Comment: But, is there any way to do it without deserializing ?

Comment: Normally front-end developers complain about returning capitalized keyname in JSON. So we can add following in the  application startup and above code will work as it is. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx

Comment: Check this for alternative, using From body http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771032/post-string-to-asp-net-web-api-application-returns-null