# How to post boolean value from ng2 service to MVC WebAPI

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am trying to post value from ng2 service to my MVC WebAPI.  It works, when the value is `false`.  It doesn't post back when the value is `true`.

My service.ts

```
EnrolStudent(HasCriminal: boolean): Observable<number> {

        console.log(HasCriminal);

        return this.http.post('/api/student/enrolstudent', HasCriminal).map(result => {
            return result.json() as number;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(new Error('Error occured in calling EnrolStudent service'));
        });

    }
```

In the above code, I can trace and clearly see that `HasCriminal` is true/false in the console.

If the value is `false`, it sends the param correctly.
[image]

However, if the value is `true`, it doesn't send out anything even though I can see `true`, in the console.[image]

Could you please suggest me how I could send this boolean value correctly to my MVC Webapi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST string to ASP.NET Web Api application - returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771032/post-string-to-asp-net-web-api-application-returns-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single primitive values you have to use url encoding. Alternatively you can wrap it in an object on the client and on the server side. Assuming you want to keep the server code unchanged here is the modification to the client code needed.

```
const options = {
    headers: new Headers({ 'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
} as RequestOptionsArgs;
const data = '=' + HasCriminal.toString();

return this.http.post('/api/student/enrolstudent', data, options).map((result: Response) => {
    return result.json() as number;
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(new Error('Error occured in calling EnrolStudent service'));
});
```