# Trying to pass Angular property to .NET API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm working in Angular 5 and Asp.Net Web API

In angular I have service and component, so component receive parameter from view like this:

```
forgotPass() {

    this.loading = true;
    debugger;
    this._authService.forgotPassword(this.model.email).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.toastr.success("Sended success")
        this.loading = false;
        LoginCustom.displaySignInForm();
        this.model = {};
      },
      error => {
        this.showAlert('alertForgotPass');
        this._alertService.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

and service execute controller like this:

```
forgotPassword(email: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/ChangePasswordToken', JSON.stringify({ email: email }), options)
      .map((response: Response) => {

      });
  }
```

As you can see I send parameter `email` to WebApi, problem is controller receive it as null, but when I debbugging JS it send email success:

[image]

Controller:

```
  [Route("ChangePasswordToken")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePasswordChangeToken(string email)
        {//code there}
```

Why I always get null in controller if angular sended it correctly? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the client model as `{ email: email }` you are defining an object that will be sent to the server. But on the server side you expect a string.

To solve this, you could:

**Either** define a C# model which matches the client model

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then read the model from the request body in the api method

```
[Route("ChangePasswordToken")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePasswordChangeToken([FromBody]EmailModel model)
{//model.Email }
```

**Or**, change the signature of the client model to be just a *=string*

`this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/ChangePasswordToken', JSON.stringify({ email: email }), options)` 
to 
`this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/ChangePasswordToken', "=" + email, options)`
then read the string from the request body

```
[Route("ChangePasswordToken")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePasswordChangeToken([FromBody]string email)
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771032/post-string-to-asp-net-web-api-application-returns-null) another answer on reading string directly from the body

Comment: and why I can't pass it as simple string as I do? what's problem there? I don't understand

Comment: I try it with both solutions but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a JSON object as param and try to receive it as a string. Hence it fails.

If you want to send a single string a param, you could try forms encoding like below:

change the content type to

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

and request should be:

```
this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/ChangePasswordToken', "=" + email, options)
```