# how to use Management API in Windows Form / C# - but The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a problem in API Management, I want to create images in item 1 item, but I still can not do it forever. I use c # language, I feel depressed
i want to create a resource in catchoom.

> can you help me

```
 byte[] buffer = null;
        byte[] data = null;
        byte[] data1 = null;
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        long length = 0;
        string boundary = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        //  string boundary = "AaB03x";
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        // Create the HttpWebRequest object
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://crs.catchoom.com/api/v0/image/?api_key=5aba12ba6974c04ebc95da45ba1597d27d75238f");
        // Specify the ContentType
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

        // Specify the Method
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        // Create the StringBuilder object
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Constrcut the POST header message
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("--" + boundary);
        sb.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"anh\"");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("/api/v0/item/aee726ff67274fcb80f4c24f27861c1e/");
        sb.AppendLine("--" + boundary);
        sb.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"anh\"; filename=\"anh\"");
        sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb1.AppendLine("");
        sb1.AppendLine("--" + boundary + "--");
        // Convert the StringBuilder into a string
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        data1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb1.ToString());
        // 
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\17. NHATLINH\ToolKit_Catchoom\ToolKit_Catchoom\bin\Debug\aa.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            length = data.Length + fs.Length + data1.Length;

            // đưa thông tin chiều dài của gói gửi đi vào
            request.ContentLength = length;
            //
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // ghi header vào gói gửi đi
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                // 
                buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fs.Length))];
                // buffer = new Byte[fs.Length];
                // Write the file contents 
                while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                }
                stream.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);
                //
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(request.ContentType);
                    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString() + sb1.ToString());
                    WebResponse responce = request.GetResponse();
                    Stream s = responce.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }
                catch (Exception ec)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Building a multipart-encoded request is an error-prone task ( it is normal if you feel frustrated trying ), I recommend you to use a library to handle this kind of things, no point in reinventing the wheel :)

If you are using the Microsoft .NET Framework >= 4.5, you may use the HttpClient class as [this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload).

Hope this help you ;)