# Upload file with api not working on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I want to upload file with api, but also I need to send 'ID'.
Same code is working in local, but does not working on IIS.

```
        [HttpPost("{id}")]
        [Route("Upload/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(int id)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
                {
                    // . . . more logic    
                }
            }

            return new OkResult();
        }
```

In Local:
[image]
On IIS
[image]

Comment: The Referer is different in case of IIS. Do you have a virtual Directory named dataset?

Comment: All other  api-s on same page are working fine. Just this one has issue.

Comment: Please try setting the content type for the HttpClient's post content. Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425043/upload-image-using-httpclient and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload

Comment: in iis  Adding MIME Types  reffer this link for adding MIME  type -[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx)   and  show all MIMe type for all file reffer this link add  mime type for zip file --[link](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Comment: I found solution, it is very stupid. On client in angular I had   "path url: '/api/transfer/upload/' + 8" instead of   "url: 'api/transfer/upload/' + 8". JUST ONE SLASH and not working on IIS !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution, it is very stupid.

On client in TypeScript I had.

```
 this.$upload.upload({
                url: '/api/transfer/upload/' + this.id,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                file: file,
                fileName: file.name,
            })...
```

Instead of

```
 this.$upload.upload({
                url: 'api/transfer/upload/' + this.id,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                file: file,
                fileName: file.name,
            })
```

JUST ONE SLASH in url path and not working on IIS !