# Form post method complete coding

Tags: c#, html, web, webserver

Following is the HTML form code, for uploading text value and a JPEG file.

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<form action="https://mywebsiteforexample.com/"  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="id" value="01"/>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="send">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is whenever I have to upload the file on server, I need to manually browse the file to upload it. I want to write the same code in C# so when I run the code it itself select the file by path given, and upload the file so I don't need to browse and select the file manually. Is it possible.

Comment: Browsers force user interaction on file uploads for security reasons.

Comment: yes but is it possible to code the same using c# to eliminate interaction?

Comment: since you can use c# to build asp.net applications I misunderstood your question. See csharpfolk answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write code that fills `input` elements (if you want, use Selenium with C# driver). Just simulate `POST` action from simple console application using for e.g. HttpClient.

There are plenty of questions on SO how to do it, e.g. [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)