# Generic and efficient way to send files from a Controller to remote ApiController in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a multi-level ASP.NET MVC web platform and I have the requirement to send a file from a `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` to an ASP.NET MVC web-service's `System.Web.Http.ApiController`, running remotely on a different machine.

Currently, I have this in my `Mvc.Controller`:

```
public ActionResult ForwardThisFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // TODO: Forward file to remote DocumentApi:
    DocumentApi.DocumentApiClient client = new DocumentApi.DocumentApiClient();
    client.StoreDocument(file /* <-- How-To? */);
    return View();
}
```

where the `DocumentApiClient` has been generated via Visual Studio's *Add REST API Client...* function from a Swagger Url. (The generated client internally uses the `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` which is relying on `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, `HttpRequestMessage`, etc.)

The question is, how do I define and implement the DocumentApi to transfer files to it in an efficient and generic way in the `ApiController`. Currently, I am thinking of three different options:

- `[HttpPut] public async Task<IHttpActionResult> StoreDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file)`
- `[HttpPut] public async Task<IHttpActionResult> StoreDocument(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileName)`
- `[HttpPut] public async Task<IHttpActionResult> StoreDocument(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileName)`

I was thinking, that maybe I could just forward the `HttpPostedFileBase` instance from the `Mvc.Controller` to the `ApiController`, so I've tried the first option. However, *Add REST API Client...* creates a `DocumentApi.Models.HttpPostedFileBase` model class in that case and is NOT of the original type `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`. Now, I'm not sure what I should do...

```
new DocumentApi.Models.HttpPostedFileBase() {
    InputStream = file.InputStream,
    ContentType = file.ContentType,
    ContentLength = file.ContentLength,
    FileName = file.FileName,
}
```

^ that doesn't work, because for the `InputStream`, it creates a `DocumentApi.Models.Stream` class and I have no idea how to convert the `System.IO.Stream` from the `file` parameter into a `DocumentApi.Models.Stream`.

Is it even possible to send a stream across ASP.NET MVC webservices? (Which would basically be the answer to option 3)

In my current state of knowledge, the only alternative appears to me being option 2, where I would send a byte-array containing the whole file. I am asking myself, however, if there is any more convenient or more efficient way to send a file from a `Mvc.Controller` to a remote `ApiController`. Is there?
Which one of the options would work and which one is the way to go?

Additionally, I have a **bonus question** to the above regarding `HttpPostedFileBase`: Is the way via `HttpPostedFileBase` the most efficient way to handle uploaded files in ASP.NET MVC? I have seen various alternatives:

- `HttpPostedFileBase` like shown above in the first code sample
- Using the raw HTTP-request via `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` or something similar. Maybe the stream is more efficient for my use case?
- Using JavaScript to encode a file into a Base64 string and send it via a hidden input field to the controller. (via `FileReader`'s method `readAsDataURL(file)`)

So many options... Which one is best/most generic/most efficient?

Comment: Why not use FileStreamResult ?

Comment: `FileStreamResult` is for returning a file, not for sending it to another remote Controller via the method described above, afaik. If there is a way, please describe in more detail!

Comment: Don't do that. The proper way is to use the http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html pattern. Send the file a an FTP location and the just send a message to the other controller to process the message you sent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the HttpClient lib in the calling controller to async upload the file to the destination controller. Various examples of using HttpClient to asycn upload is here [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload).

In this case your receiving remote controller just acts as though its having a file uploaded from a browser with no specific handling required.

Comment: In this case, I would implement the remote controller's method like option 1: `[HttpPut] public async Task<IHttpActionResult> StoreDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file)`, would I? I don't see, however, where the content type goes... there is only `"application/octet-stream"` which is required for the stream, I guess, but I need the actual file's content type as well.

Comment: What do you need the encoding for at the receiving end ?

Comment: I need to send the file back some time in the future and therefore, the content type should be correct.

Comment: You could just look at the HttpContext.Current Header "Content-Type" within the controller.