# C# multipart data uploading problems - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have the problem with posting some files using MultipartFormDataContent.
I try to use FileStream for adding file content to MultipartFormDataContent

```
var multipartMetadata = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileStream1 = File.Open("sample1.txt");
var fileStream2 = File.Open("sample2.txt");

multipartMetadata.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream1), fileData.Name, fileData.FileName);

multipartMetadata.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream2), fileData.Name, fileData.FileName);

var client = new HttpClient();

await client.PostAsync(uri, multipartMetadata);
```

InvalidOperationException was thrown during execution this code. Exception Message "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written".
 There are any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: What was the exception message?

Comment: Exception message  was "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written".

Comment: and what line does the exception occur on?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload

Comment: Exception occur on last line - client.PostAsync(uri, multipartMetadata) .

Comment: Related link provided above is not appropriate for me, because it uses MemoryStream. MemoryStream produces memory leaks for large files

Comment: can you show the code snippet where you create fileStream1 and fileStream2?

Comment: I create fileStream1/2 using simple way - 
var fileStream1 = File.OpenRead("sample1.txt");
var fileStream2 = File.OpenRead("sample2.txt");

Comment: not in a using block or anything?

Comment: It shown without any blocks, but previously i tried to use blocks 
for streams, httpClient and MultipartFormDataContent. Exception are the same for different combinations.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on `await client.PostAsync(uri, multipartMetadata);` and check the fileStream objects, are they open?

Comment: Or my god!!!! It is.... Sorry for this question. Problem has been resolved.

Comment: pquest, thank you very much!