# Post file with C#

Tags: c#, post, parameters, httpwebrequest

I would like to send file to a web service with other parametrs
Like this :

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=IMAGE_FILE
```

how can i do this in C#
I try this :

```
&param3=Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(txtlogo.Text))
```

but thats not work..
so have any solution ?

**Update :**

Also I try to use from `HttpContent` like this (i don't know it's correct or no )

```
HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent("param1=param1&param2=param2");
            FileStream file = new FileStream(txtlogo.Text, FileMode.Open);
            HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(file);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(stringContent, "param1", "param1");
                formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
                var response = client.PostAsync("url", formData).Result;
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                   string ss = "s";
                }
                string my = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
            }
```

and server don't receive any data with `POST` ...

Comment: When you say it not works? Did you tried to read the `param3` at the server and you din't get the image file?

Comment: @Christos yes but that's not work i don't know why

Comment: in particular, this answer to duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28242511/413399

Comment: @DavidCulp: if you send answer i'll accept that :)

Comment: thanks for the offer, but can't post answers to questions marked as duplicate.  Just up vote the answer on that question that worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

try with get method (simple)

```
    try
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string url = "https://url.com/index.php?x=1222&y=filebase64-sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd";
        // Get account from accessToken
        response = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Coś nie tak z pobieraniem kont");
}
```

Comment: And tutorial http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/