# C# .NetCore HttpClient PostAsync Multipart Form-Data with file attachment and progress for PowerShell use

Tags: c#, powershell, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am in the process of working on updating some PowerShell code that usesd `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` to handle file transfers to and from a web service.  The `System.IO.FileStream` class has a major problem with handling file streams being transferred to a web service using `HttpWebRequest` that Microsoft isn't going to fix or address within DotNetCore, and thus PowerShellCore ([MS PowerShell GitHub Issue 4129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4129)).  Essentially, one runs into a `Stream was too long` exception in .NetCore's legacy API implementation for `FileStream` and PowerShellCore/PowerShell7.  So, I have the following verified and working PowerShell code I am trying to convert to C# async class method using `HttpClient` to asynchronously upload files to an Apache/Spring-based REST API service:

```bsh
$Hostname   = "somewebserver"
$Method     = "POST"
$File       = Get-ChildItem C:\Directory\file.iso
$FSOpenMode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
$FSRead     = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read

# Read file using FileStream
$fs = [IO.FileStream]::new($File.FullName, $FSOpenMode, $FSRead)

[void]$fs.FlushAsync()

try
{

    # Set the URL that will be the upload destination
    $url = "https://{0}/upload?uploadfilename={1}" -f $Hostname, $File.Name

    $_DispositionContentType = "application/octet-stream"

    [System.Net.httpWebRequest]$uploadRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $uploadRequest.Method = $Method

    $boundary = "---------------------------" + [DateTime]::Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
    [byte[]]$BoundaryBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`r`n--" + $boundary + "`r`n");
    $disposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"{0}`";`r`nContent-Type: {1}`r`n`r`n" -f $File.Name, $_DispositionContentType
    [byte[]]$ContentDispBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($disposition);
    [byte[]]$EndBoundaryBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`r`n--" + $boundary + "--`r`n")

    $uploadRequest.Timeout = 1200000
    $uploadRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary={0}" -f $boundary
    $uploadRequest.Headers.Item("auth") = "SessionID"
    $uploadRequest.Headers.Item("uploadfilename") = $File.Name
    $uploadRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = $true
    $uploadRequest.SendChunked = $true
    $uploadRequest.ContentLength = $BoundaryBytes.length + $ContentDispBytes.length + $File.Length + $EndBoundaryBytes.Length
    $uploadRequest.Headers.Item("ContentLength") = $BoundaryBytes.length + $ContentDispBytes.length + $File.Length + $EndBoundaryBytes.Length

    $rs = $uploadRequest.GetRequestStream()
    [void]$rs.FlushAsync()

    [byte[]]$readbuffer = [byte[]]::new(4096 * 1024)
    $rs.write($BoundaryBytes, 0, $BoundaryBytes.Length);
    $rs.write($ContentDispBytes, 0, $ContentDispBytes.Length);

    # This is used to keep track of the file upload progress.
    $numBytesToRead = $fs.Length
    [int64]$numBytesRead = 0

    $_sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $_progresssw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

    while ($bytesRead = $fs.Read($readbuffer, 0, $readbuffer.length))
    {

        [void]$fs.Flush()

        $rs.write($readbuffer, 0, $bytesRead)

        [void]$fs.Flush()
        [void]$rs.Flush()

        # Keep track of where we are at clearduring the read operation
        $_numBytesRead += $bytesRead

        # Flush the buffer every 200ms and 1MB written
        if ($_progresssw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -ge 200 -and $_numBytesRead % 100mb -eq 0)
        {

            [void]$rs.flush()

        }

        # Use the Write-Progress cmd-let to show the progress of uploading the file.
        [Int]$_percent = [math]::floor(($_numBytesRead / $fs.Length) * 100)

        # Elapsed time to calculat throughput
        [Int]$_elapsed = $_sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000

        if ($_elapsed -ne 0 )
        {

            [single]$_transferrate = [Math]::Round(($_numBytesRead / $_elapsed) / 1mb)

        }

        else
        {

            [single]$_transferrate = 0.0

        }

        $status = "({0:0}MB of {1:0}MB transferred @ {2}MB/s) Completed {3}%" -f ($_numBytesRead / 1MB), ($numBytesToRead / 1MB), $_transferrate, $_percent

        # Handle how poorly Write-Progress adds latency to the file transfer process by only refreshing the progress at a specifc interval
        if ($_progresssw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -ge 500)
        {

            if ($_numBytesRead % 1mb -eq 0)
            {

                Write-Progress -activity "Upload File" -status ("Uploading '{0}'" -f $File.Name) -CurrentOperation $status -PercentComplete $_percent

            }

        }

    }


    $fs.close()

    # Write the endboundary to the file's binary upload stream
    $rs.write($EndBoundaryBytes, 0, $EndBoundaryBytes.Length)

    $rs.close()

    $_sw.stop()
    $_sw.Reset()

    Write-Progress -activity "Upload File" -status ("Uploading '{0}'" -f $File.Name)  -Complete

}

catch [System.Exception]
{

    if ($fs)
    {

        $fs.close()

    }

    if ($_sw.IsRunning)
    {

        $_sw.Stop()
        $_sw.Reset()

    }

    # Dispose if still exist
    if ($rs)
    {

        $rs.close()

    }

    Throw $_

}

try
{

    # Indicate we are waiting for the API to process the uploaded file in the write progress display
    Write-Progress -activity "Upload File" -status ("Uploading '{0}'" -f $File.Name)  -CurrentOperation "Waiting for completion response from appliance." -percentComplete $_percent

    # Get the response from the API on the progress of identifying the file
    [Net.httpWebResponse]$WebResponse = $uploadRequest.getResponse()
    $uploadResponseStream = $WebResponse.GetResponseStream()

    # Read the response & convert to JSON
    $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($uploadResponseStream)
    $responseJson = $reader.ReadToEnd()

    $uploadResponse = ConvertFrom-Json $responseJson

    $uploadResponseStream.Close()

    $uploadRequest = $Null

    # Finalize write progress display
    Write-Progress -activity "Upload File" -CurrentOperation "Uploading $Filename " -Completed

}

catch [Net.WebException]
{

    if ($null -ne $_.Exception.Response)
    {

        Try
        {

            # Need to see if Response is not empty

            $sr = [IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())

        }

        Catch
        {

            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)

        }

        $errorObject = $sr.readtoEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json

        # dispose if still exist
        if ($rs)
        {

            $rs.close()

        }

        if ($fs)
        {

            $fs.close()

        }

        $sr.close()

        # This New-ErrorRecord is an internal function that generates a new System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord object to then throw
        $ErrorRecord = New-ErrorRecord HPEOneview.Appliance.UploadFileException $errorObject.ErrorCode InvalidResult 'Upload-File' -Message $errorObject.Message -InnerException $_.Exception

        Throw $ErrorRecord

    }

    else
    {

       Throw $_

    }

}
```

The following *working* C# code is the result of some research I have done to try to understand how `HttpClient` works with multipart/form-data uploads:

```cs
public class HttpClientUpload : IDisposable
{

    private readonly string _uploadUrl;
    private readonly string _sourceFilePath;
    private readonly string _authToken;

    // THIS IS ONLY HERE FOR TESTING
    private static HttpClientHandler _handler = new HttpClientHandler() { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; } };
    private HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(_handler)
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
    };

    public delegate void ProgressChangedHandler(long? totalFileSize, long totalBytesDownloaded, double? progressPercentage);

    public event ProgressChangedHandler ProgressChanged;

    public HttpClientUpload(string uploadUrl, string sourceFilePath, string authToken)
    {
        _uploadUrl = uploadUrl;
        _sourceFilePath = sourceFilePath;
        _authToken = authToken;
    }

    // Borrowed code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload
    public void UploadAsync()
    {

        var Path = _sourceFilePath;
        var Appliance = _uploadUrl;
        var AuthToken = _authToken;

        var m_CancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = m_CancellationSource.Token;
        var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
        var uri = $"https://{Appliance}/rest/firmware-bundles?uploadfilename={fileInfo.Name}";

        // If the file extension is CRL, we need to use a different disposition/mime type declaration.
        var DispositionContentType = fileInfo.Extension == "crl" ? "application/pkix-crl" : "application/octet-stream";

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", $"Custom User Agent ({Environment.OSVersion.ToString()})");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Version", "1800");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("auth", AuthToken);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("uploadfilename", fileInfo.Name);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "en_US");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")))
        {

            content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{fileInfo.Name}\"");

            content.Headers.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;

            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Path);

            var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
            streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", $"{DispositionContentType}");
            streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{fileInfo.Name}\"");
            content.Add(streamContent, "file", fileInfo.FullName);

            Task<HttpResponseMessage> message = _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);

            var input = message.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(input.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

    }

    public void Stop()
    {

        _httpClient.CancelPendingRequests();

        throw new OperationCanceledException("File upload cancelled.");

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

        _httpClient?.Dispose();

    }

}
```

The code above can be invoked from PowerShell as such:

```bsh
$Hostname  = "somewebserver"
$AuthToken = "SessionID"
$FileName  = 'C:\directory\somefile.iso'
$Task      = ([HttpClientUpload]::new($Hostname, $FileName, $AuthToken)).UploadAsync()
```

The file appears to be transferred to the target, but te API endpoint generates an error (not an HTTP error, but a JSON response that it couldn't parse the file) and I get this in our API application log file:

> caught apache common fileuploadexception ex=Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly while uploading file somefile.iso

I know that this is caused by the fact that the request from the client must append a byte array of an endboundary.  Because without it, I would get the very same message with the original PowerShell code I currently use if I omit the following line(s):

```bsh
    # Write the endboundary to the file's binary upload stream
    $rs.write($EndBoundaryBytes, 0, $EndBoundaryBytes.Length)
```

These are the following posts I have seen, but have only been a bit helpful in understanding the basic function of attaching a filestream object to an `HttpClient` object:

- [Progress bar with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient)
- [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload) (this one is close, but doesn’t offer tracking of progress, and am unsure how to attach an Event to it, let alone needing to chunk the upload for a FileStream, not MemoryStream)
- [post multipart/form-data in c# HttpClient 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229368/post-multipart-form-data-in-c-sharp-httpclient-4-5/50462636#50462636)
- [How to display upload progress using C# HttpClient PostAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320238/how-to-display-upload-progress-using-c-sharp-httpclient-postasync)
- [C#: HttpClient, File upload progress when uploading multiple file as MultipartFormDataContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378457/c-httpclient-file-upload-progress-when-uploading-multiple-file-as-multipartfo) (the post here marked as the Correct answer doesn’t appear right to me, especially when the code is documented for Download, not upload)
- [How can I calculate progress with HttpClient PostAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528839/how-can-i-calculate-progress-with-httpclient-postasync)

So, the TL;DR to my post.  My questions are:

1. How does one ensure that a multipart/form-data request that needs to include a binary stream of a file contains the start and end boundary for the `HttpClient` request?
2. Any guidance on how to then chunk the file stream in order to report buffer transfer progress?  I intend to read this from PowerShell after the async task has begun, in order to use `Write-Progress` back to the user.