# Bad request 400 "Fiel field is required" Error while Posting IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm making a Web API and I need to post data to another API controller.

The API method POST of the controller looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> 
           ImportFile([FromForm] ImportData data)
   {
var result = await _service.ImportData(data);
return Ok(result);
   }
```

The ImportData looks like this:

```
public class ImportData
{
    [Required]
    public IFormFile File {get;set;}
    
    [Required]
    public string name{get;set;}
}
```

I have the same DTO to consume the endpoint of the controller, but for the IFormFile I only have available a encoded64 string, so in my DTO I substitute IFormFile for byte[].

How do I generate the IFormFile with the string to feed the DTO and make the request?

How do I populate the form of the request?(because the controller has [FromForm]

My current request:

```
ImportDataDTO data = new ImportDataDTO ();
   data.file = Convert.FromBase64String(encodeStringFile);

 data.name = "my name";
 await httpclient.PostAsync(URL, data);
```

Regards

Comment: please post the way you are requesting it

Comment: @DanielA.White there you have it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [post multipart/form-data in c# HttpClient 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229368/post-multipart-form-data-in-c-sharp-httpclient-4-5)

Comment: `IFormFile` is for non JSON files - its for a normal form upload

Comment: @DanielA.White yes that I know. But I'm a bit lost. The `IFormFile` that the controller is specting  is a XML. But I Only have the base64 string of the encoded XML file. So I need to send that my model, with the XML(`IFormFile`) and the string name. All of that in `[FromForm]`. Do I need to mock the `IFormFile` first maybe?

Comment: Could you pls tell us your requirement and what issue you met now? As your description, it seems that your api received a request with a file, and then you want send the file data to another api. So why you need to transfer to string? first but not send the file data directly? I can't understand here.