# Smart File API upload files

Tags: c#, httpclient

I hate this API....
The documentation states:

> POST /api/2/path/data/Documents/ HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data
>
> Content-Length: length of request body here
>
> multi-part data here

So I created this:

```
    public async Task<bool> UploadAsync(string path, string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        EnforceBasicAuthentication();
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
        byteContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        byteContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Name = "file"
        };
        var form = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            byteContent
        };
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_config.FtpUrl}/path/data/{_config.FtpPath}/{path}", form);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return true;
    }
```

But every time I run it, I get a 400 bad request error. It doesn't say anything other than that.
Looking at my code, is there anything that looks wrong?

---

I have tried multiple solutions and none of them seem to work.
Currently I have this:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadAsync(string path, string fileName, byte[] data)
{
    EnforceBasicAuthentication();

    var boundary = "--------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    var bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    form.Add(bytesContent, "file", fileName);
    form.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    form.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", $"multipart/form-data; boundary= { boundary }");
    bytesContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_config.FtpUrl}/path/data/{_config.FtpPath}/{path}", form);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return true;
}
```

But it still throws a 400 error.
I have configured Fiddler and done a test in postman. The test in postman worked fine. Here is the request in fiddler:

> POST https://app.smartfile.com/api/2/path/data/eOrdering/GRE017 HTTP/1.1
>
> cache-control: no-cache
>
> Postman-Token: 8359aae8-f4e2-4864-b81a-0169fe3f2b62
>
> Authorization: Basic bleh
>
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Host: app.smartfile.com
>
> cookie: csrftoken=rsDaPbfwG070rwBFlhIWVvULcAqGW0GB;
>
> sessionid=a744788776bfef3c44faf6eb5e2a2931
>
> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------606952503302468487113354
>
> content-length: 334
>
> Connection: close
>
> ----------------------------606952503302468487113354
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="S200-220311-20180606095501.ord"
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> 274            274/1 |PAULA|00220311|STD|||ASAP
>
> 1|23133|1313  131302   4.00|C|3.65|||12/06/18
>
> ----------------------------606952503302468487113354--

And this is the one generated by my code:

> POST https://app.smartfile.com/api/2/path/data/eOrdering/GRE017 HTTP/1.1
>
> Authorization: Basic blah
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------8d5d140cf824278
>
> Host: app.smartfile.com
>
> Cookie: csrftoken=NYOgu61I6ddqBgudQEhWNr27fJUEQFi3;
>
> sessionid=6994ad9254ebc46e0611e6ac308d6c55
>
> Content-Length: 375
>
> --52343329-f101-43a2-b4bb-bfa9a4073f6e
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=3c3f1596-707b-4725-9766-25faf6124a35.rsl; filename*=utf-8''3c3f1596-707b-4725-9766-25faf6124a35.rsl
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> Fail|"Price Issue Number is invalid, must be greater than 0"|
>
> 1|23133|01/01/0001 00:00:00|0|0
>
> --52343329-f101-43a2-b4bb-bfa9a4073f6e--

I still have no idea why it is failing :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)

Comment: Also verify and mayb post that url + query. Can you use PostMan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured this out after spending ages on it.
There are two issues that needed to be addressed. The first one was the double **fileName** (which also had no double quotes around them) and the second was the boundary....
In the end, I changed my code to look like this:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadAsync(string path, string fileName, byte[] data)
{
    EnforceBasicAuthentication();
    var bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    bytesContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
    bytesContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"file\"",
        FileName = $"\"{fileName}\""
    };
    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent { bytesContent };
    var boundary = formData.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.First(o => o.Name == "boundary");
    boundary.Value = boundary.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_config.FtpUrl}/path/data/{_config.FtpPath}/{path}", formData);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return true;
}
```

As you can see there, for the `ContentDisposition` I added the name and filename (with \" because of a bug....) and for the `FormData` content type, I had to remove the extra double quotes.

Really annoying, but finally working....

Answer (score -1):

Try your byte data into var content = new ByteArrayContent(filedata);
and pass content to PostAsync something like below:

```
var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
var ApiRequest = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
```