# HTTP Post removing content from data

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

Here is my code

```
var postData = "country=1";
postData += "&desktop_api=fsdf";
postData += "&adata=" + adData;
postData += "&about_page_data=" + aboutPageContent;
postData += "&url=" + url;

StringContent content = new StringContent("data=" + postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage sResponse = await client.PostAsync(siteUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`adData` has over 2 million characters, but on my server I only receive around 2800 characters.

Comment: Op means  200k @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: 2 lakh ==> 2,00,000

Comment: Is it properly URL Encoded as the header promises it to be?

Comment: how we can do it?

Comment: Use Fiddler or Wireshark to prove that you're _sending_ the content, vs. the server _receiving_ it.

Answer (score 1):

Url encoded post type is sometimes too limiting for a large amount of data, due to the fact it is one long url, using multipart form data solves this problem, this has previously been explained better then i can here : [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

without seeing the value of **adData** it would be difficult to tell you if you have a bad character that is causing issues. but for safety, you should ensure that your variables are UrlEncoded:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.110).aspx

TLDR:

```
var postData = "country=1";

  postData += "&desktop_api=fsdf";
  postData += "&adata=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(adData);;
  postData += "&about_page_data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(aboutPageContent);;
  postData += "&url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

OR

if you need a multipart example : [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)