# TFS Nuget Publisher task fails with 401 No credentials are available in the security package

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget

I have a Build pipeilne with following tasks:

[image]

**Task Parameters**

1. 'Build and Package' - .NET Core

   1. Command: `pack`
   2. Project(s): `src/Camelot.Domain.csproj`
   3. Arguments: `--configuration Release --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/package /p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)`
2. 'Publish Packages' - NuGet Publisher

   1. Path/Pattern: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/package/*.nupkg`
   2. Feed Type: `Internal Nuget Feed`
   3. Internal Feed Url: `https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json`
   4. NuGet Version: `3.5.0`

**Command Line Tool Details**

The command line task is a custom utility we use that runs on the `Build.SourceDirectory` and does two things.

1. It modifies all `*.csproj` files to change `ProjectReferences` into `PackageReferences` that are located in our internal TFS feed.
2. It creates a `NuGet.config` file at the root of the `Build.SourceDirectory` that adds our internal feed as a NuGet source and also provides the agent credentials token.

**Command Line Task Output**

```
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z NuGet.config Contents
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z <configuration>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z   <config>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z     <add key="http_proxy" value="http://XXX:9191" />
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z     <add key="https_proxy" value="http://XXX:9191" />
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z   </config>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z   <packageSources>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z     <add key="KAT.Nuget.Feed" value="https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z   </packageSources>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z   <packageSourceCredentials>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z     <KAT.Nuget.Feed>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z       <add key="Username" value="TFS.Build.Release" />
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z       <add key="ClearTextPassword" value=******** />
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z       <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z     </KAT.Nuget.Feed>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z   </packageSourceCredentials>
2024-02-11T19:26:41.1007340Z </configuration>
```

**Details/My Assumptions**

I've narrowed down the problem to the creation of the `NuGet.config`.  If I change my command line utility to **NOT save** a `NuGet.config` file (but still do all other processing) everything works.

1. The `NuGet.config` should **not** be used by NuGet Publisher (nuget.exe) since it is not discoverable in the `*.nupkg` file (or any of its parent's) path.

   1. The NuGet.config file that is created is located at `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, something like `D:\tfs.agent\_work\26\s\NuGet.config`.
   2. The `*.nupkg` are generated and used by NuGet Publisher in the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/package` folder, something like `D:\tfs.agent\_work\26\a\*.nupkg`
2. The 'accessToken' used by the command line tool and the `ClearTextPassword` value in `NuGet.config` is simply the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` token passed in via enabling the `Allow scripts to access OAuth token` option in the Build pipeline.
3. As Andy Li pointed out below, the Build pipeline runs as `Project Collection Build Service` and I'm assuming that the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` token passed to and used by the tool is the same account and is 'valid' since NuGet Publisher succeeds when I don't create the `NuGet.config` file.  As displayed by image of security settings below, the account seems to be configured correctly on the feed.

[image]

**Questions**

When a `NuGet.config` file is created, NuGet Publisher fails with the following (relevant details from the) log.

1. Why does it say `No credentials are available in the security package` when it seems that in fact that there **is/was** security information (via my `NuGet.config`) provided?
2. It was suggested to 'try the process locally'.  I'm not sure how I would do that.  How would I get an 'accessToken'?  Is this just a Personal Access Token (PAT) that I create?
3. Assuming I end up having to run a command line task to publish my package myself, is there a way (or environment variable) that can give me the path to the (correct version of) `nuget.exe` file?

**NuGet Publisher Task Output**

```
2024-02-12T13:22:59.3031977Z Detected NuGet version 3.5.0.1938 / 3.5.0
2024-02-12T13:22:59.3031977Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2024-02-12T13:22:59.3187978Z [command]D:\tfs.agent\_work\_tasks\NuGetPublisher_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f25b\0.2.34\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe push -NonInteractive D:\tfs.agent\_work\25\a\package\KAT.Camelot.Domain.1.0.27.nupkg -Source https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey VSTS -Verbosity Detailed
2024-02-12T13:22:59.9125618Z NuGet Version: 3.5.0.1938
2024-02-12T13:23:00.0219336Z Pushing KAT.Camelot.Domain.1.0.27.nupkg to 'https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/'...
2024-02-12T13:23:00.1000648Z   PUT https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/
2024-02-12T13:23:00.6782231Z An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/'. The request will now be retried.
2024-02-12T13:23:00.6782231Z An error occurred while sending the request.
2024-02-12T13:23:00.6782231Z   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
2024-02-12T13:23:00.6782231Z   No credentials are available in the security package
2024-02-12T13:23:00.8969873Z   PUT https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/
2024-02-12T13:23:01.3344956Z An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/'. The request will now be retried.
2024-02-12T13:23:01.3344956Z An error occurred while sending the request.
2024-02-12T13:23:01.3344956Z   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
2024-02-12T13:23:01.3344956Z   No credentials are available in the security package
2024-02-12T13:23:01.5522529Z   PUT https://tfs.XXX.com/tfs/XXX/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/
2024-02-12T13:23:01.9897867Z System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; Using the [NuGet Push Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-publish-resource) I was able to make this work.

Following the suggestion of Andy Li, I attempted to simply use a Command Line task that wrapped a call to `nuget push` via the following:

```cs
var nugetExe = Path.Combine( agentHomeDirectory, @"utilities\nuget.3.5.0\nuget.exe" );

var publishCommand = Cli.Wrap( nugetExe )
    .WithWorkingDirectory( packageDirectory )
    .WithArguments( new string[] { 
        "push", Path.GetFileName( packageFile ), 
        "-src", "KAT.Nuget.Feed", 
        "-Verbosity", "normal", 
        "-ConfigFile", nugetConfig, 
        "-NonInteractive", 
        "-ApiKey", "VSTS" 
    } )!;

await publishCommand.ExecuteBufferedAsync();
```

Note, using the [CliWrap library](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) I was simply calling a copied `3.5.0` version of `nuget.exe` from the utilities folder of the TFS build agent.  I also was using the `-ConfigFile` param to point at the file I created with feed configuration and credentials.

However, executing this, still failed with the following:

```
Executing: `D:\tfs.agent\utilities\nuget.3.5.0\nuget.exe push KAT.Camelot.Domain.1.0.40.nupkg -src KAT.Nuget.Feed -Verbosity detailed -ConfigFile D:\tfs.agent\_work\25\s\NuGet.config -NonInteractive -ApiKey VSTS`
Unable to process TFS CI/CD command(s).
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://tfs.XXXX.com/tfs/XXXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package
```

I am fairly certain it was correctly using the `D:\tfs.agent\_work\25\s\NuGet.config` configuration file because it could resolve `-src KAT.Nuget.Feed` to the correct url of `https://tfs.XXXX.com/tfs/XXXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json` but it did not use the correct credentials.

Again reviewing the suggested commands to run:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "KAT.Nuget.Feed" -Source https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/XXXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json -UserName MyUserName -Password value -config ./nuget.config
nuget push nupkgs/mypackage.1.1.8.nupkg -src MySource -ApiKey AZ
```

I decided to run these manually on the build server to see what happened. Two points worth mentioning:

1. In the `NuGet.config` file updated from the `Add` command, the `packageSourceCredentials` section was updated with the `UserName` and `Password` instead of `ClearTextPassword` which I had been using. If I was to use this, I was going to have to figure out how to create the proper format for that because just using `{AccessToken}` was not permitted.
2. If I ran the `Add` command on the build server and passed in the `{AccessToken}` value for the `-Password` parameter, it did the encoding for me. I then attempted a `push`, but I received the exact same error as before.

Finally, I decided to try and use the [NuGet Push Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-publish-resource) since I was already successfully  authenticating and using the [NuGet Search Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource).  The PUT request was implemented as follows:

```cs
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Put, "https://tfs.XXXX.com/tfs/XXXX/_packaging/XXXX/nuget/v2/" )
{
    Content = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { new ByteArrayContent( await File.ReadAllBytesAsync( packageFile ) ), "file", Path.GetFileName( packageFile ) }
    }
};

using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync( request );
```

This also threw an exception and returned the following response:

> Bad Request.  Expected a single 'application/octet-stream' part.

**Finally...Success!**

Following this [Stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176740/uploading-multipart-form-files-with-httpclient#comment106464323_60191497) I added a `ContentType` to the `ByteArrayContent` and the `NuGet Push Api` worked.  The final implementation was:

```cs
var binaryContent = new ByteArrayContent( await File.ReadAllBytesAsync( packageFile ) );
binaryContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "application/octet-stream" );

using var request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Put, "https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/PDSI/_packaging/5dbfd80f-1bf7-4a6d-b222-6049c75603fe/nuget/v2/" )
{
    Content = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { binaryContent, "file", Path.GetFileName( packageFile ) }
    }
};

using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync( request );
```

**UPDATE**: Note that the NuGet proxy information **has** to be stored in the global NuGet.config.  When it was only in my generated file, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "`NuGet Publisher`" task use the `Project Collection Build Service` account to publish the packages to the feed. It seems that the process is destroyed by the `Command Line` task. It tries to use `NuGet.config` to do the authorization.

Firstly, please make sure the credential you provided in the `NuGet.config` has the correct permission to publish packages to the feed. If possible, you can try the process locally to see if it has the same issue.

Secondly, you can try to add a command line task and run the nuget commands directly to publish the packages instead of the "`NuGet Publisher`" task to see if it works:

For example:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "KAT.Nuget.Feed" -Source https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/XXXX/_packaging/KAT.Nuget.Feed/nuget/v3/index.json -UserName MyUserName -Password value -config ./nuget.config
    
nuget push nupkgs/mypackage.1.1.8.nupkg -src MySource -ApiKey AZ
```

Comment: I've reworked my question as I've discovered that the single point of failure is the creation of the `NuGet.config` file.  To your questions: I think the credential I provided has rights (as stated in the question above) because I assume it is just the token for `Project Collection Build Service`.  'Try locally', I don't really know how to do that and put some details in the question about that.  Finally, command line, I added question about detecting nuget.exe, but also, shouldn't `ApiKey` be `VSTS` like the publisher tried to use?

Comment: I posted an answer for documentation purposes to anyone else that might search at various stages of attempting to implement it.  But running a command line task to use the NuGet Push Api got me there (all else failed).

Comment: 1. Had to wait 24 hours to accept post.  2. FYI, turns out that my statement about proxy info inside my generated nuget.config file doesn't work.  It **has** to be in the global file for some reason.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for your sharing. It's time to accept your post as an Answer :).