# How to make a post request with body option form-data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Would anyone know how to convert the below Postman POST Body form-data parameters to C# POST request, I tried a lot using HttpClient, Web request at my end but it's not working.

[image]

Sample code:

```
var bytes = (dynamic)null;
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
 {
    using (var multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(documentData);
    
        //Add file to the multipart request
        multiPartContent.Headers.Add("format_source", FORMAT_SOURCE);
        multiPartContent.Headers.Add("format_target", FORMAT_TARGET);
        multiPartContent.Add(fileContent);
    
        //Post it
        bytes = httpClient.PostAsync(CONVERSION_URL, multiPartContent).Result;
    }
}
```

Postman code:
C# RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://test-service-staging.test.com/convert");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddFile("input", "/C:/Users/DR-11/Downloads/response_1592912235925.xml");
request.AddParameter("format_source", "abc");
request.AddParameter("format_target", "xyz");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

HTTP:

```
POST /convert HTTP/1.1
Host: test-service-staging.test.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"; filename="/C:/Users/DR-11/Downloads/response_1592912235925.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format_source"

abc
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format_target"

xyz
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://test-service-staging.test.com/convert' \
--form 'input=@/C:/Users/DR-11/Downloads/response_1592912235925.xml' \
--form 'format_source=abc' \
--form 'format_target=xyz'
```

Instead of file path, need to pass the bytes in the API.

Comment: In postman, if you click on the `Code` button (pictured in the top right hand corner) that will give you a coding sample.

Comment: In c# code You are adding values in header while you should be adding them in body. Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)

Comment: var client = new RestClient("http://test-service-staging.test.com/convert");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddFile("input", "/C:/Users/DR-11/Downloads/response_1592912235925.xml");
request.AddParameter("format_source", "abc");
request.AddParameter("format_target", "xyz");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

Thanks @AndrewE but it's not working in .net core 2.2

Comment: is the url a working one? also you are displaying the content to the console but you requests appears to be return bytes rather than plain text?

Comment: No, I included a dummy one. I want the same using http client not using RestClient library.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Here is an example of your postman request using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1).
It was hard to test this without a live url, however this should hopefully help you.
Not sure if you are wanting a string or byte array for the return type, I have chosen a string however if you do want a byte array, something like this should do the trick
`static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> SendDataAsync()` 
`return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`

```
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Is This Returning A String Or Bytes
        string responseAsString = await SendDataAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> SendDataAsync()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        using (MultipartFormDataContent formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            // Create Form Values
            KeyValuePair<string, string>[] keyValuePairs = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("format_source", "abc"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("format_target", "xyz")
            };

            // Loop Each KeyValuePair Item And Add It To The MultipartFormDataContent.
            foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
            {
                formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
            }

            // Get The ByteArrayContent,Reading Bytes From The Give File Path.
            // Adding It To The MultipartFormDataContent Once File Is Read.
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\andrew.eberle\Desktop\data.xml";
            ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

            // Add Content Type For MediaTypeHeaderValue.
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            // Add The File Under ''input'
            formDataContent.Add(fileContent, "input", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            // Post Request And Wait For The Response.
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://test-service-staging.test.com/convert", formDataContent);

            // Check If Successful Or Not.
            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Return Byte Array To The Caller.
                return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                // Throw Some Sort of Exception?
                return default;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about first parameter i.e input has value File, I have file bytes and passing in the code that you provided above and getting 500 error.

Comment: Updated, I have added input to the formDataContent, see how you go, Without a way to test we're flying blind. Hopefully this gets you one step closer.

Comment: Now I am getting 400, It means the previous one is fine but there is something that needs to be fixed. Let me edit the code part, going to add the source code using C# RestSharp, Curl, Http. It will give a clear picture of what is missing in this code.

Comment: Updated, tested with webapi and received the parameters and file `formDataContent.Add(fileContent, "input", $"{System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");` forgot to add the filename to the previous comment, if the server doesnt like the `MediaTypeHeaderValue` you should be able to comment it out to test.

Comment: keep trying the updated code, but getting 400 status.

Comment: -  httpResponseMessage {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2020 16:48:39 GMT
  Server: nginx/1.16.1
  Via: HTTP/1.1 forward.http.proxy:3128
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 106
}} System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Comment: What about when you read the httpresponse string when you get the error? Looks like there could be a reason for the error.

Comment: This is the message that I am getting in HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage. no other specific error details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216909/discussion-between-andrewe-and-jayoti-parkash).