# Send parameters & file in Request Body with Origin Request Header C#

Tags: c#, post, webclient, dotnet-httpclient, request-headers

I am trying to send parameters & file in Request Body with Origin Request Header C# Console / Asp.Net (Web Form) Web Application.
I have looked around many examples but I didn't get proper solutions.

I've tried with the following code which is almost working. The only issue with couldn't get any solution to **send the file in Request Body**.

```
 public class requestObj
        {
            public string langType { get; set; }
        }

protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {           
                var requestObj = new requestObj
                {
                    langType = "aaa"
                };

                var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
                request.AddJsonBody(requestObj);
                var response = client.Execute(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload

Comment: Thanks for your response... I will check sure check this.. but can we do using WebClient ? Do you have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have made it working following ways,

```
string url = requestUrl;
string filePath = @"F:\text.txt";


 var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
                    client.Timeout = -1;
                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                    request.AddHeader("Origin", "http://localhost:2020");
                    request.AddParameter("parameter", "parameterValue");
                    request.AddFile("file", filePath, "text/plain"); //file parameter.
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```