# how can I transfer curl command to C# HttpClient with cert

Tags: c#, curl, dotnet-httpclient, aws-iot-core

I wrote a curl example to use the rest API of "aws iot core" and confirmed that it was operating. However, in the authentication process in the C# http client, I do not know how to insert the following three authentication values.

I would appreciate it if I could get help.

Below is the curl phrase:

```
curl --tlsv1.2 --cacert AmazonRootCA1.txt \
    --cert test_thing.cert.pem \
    --key test_thing.private.key \
    --request POST \
    --data "test gogo" \
    "https://[iot_url].iot.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com:8443/topics/topic_2?qos=1" \
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload