# How to read both from request URI and body in ASP.NET MVC controller and AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller with attribute and signature

```
[HttpPost] 
public void SubmitOrder(string id, string user, [FromBody]string data)
```

that has a custom route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Submit",
    url: "Order/{id}/{user}/Submit",
    defaults: new { controller = "Order", action = "SubmitOrder", id = "", user = "" }
);
```

Next, I have an AJAX post as:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "aaa/bbb/Submit",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(newData),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
});
```

I can reach SubmitOrder() where `id = aaa` and `user = bbb` have the proper values from the URL, but `data` is always null. I don't want to change the route, and want the JSON object to be in the request body (I know I can set an additional parameter in the route, but for design reasons I'd rather have it in the request body instead). However, I don't know how to access this data from the controller. Is there a way to read the request body without making changes to the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax call, try

```
data: { data: json.stringify (newdata) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, this didn't work (the ajax call wouldn't even reach the endpoint at all, for some reason), but instead I moved the JSON.stringify() to the outside: `JSON.stringify({data: newData})` and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do both.

Make sure you have the following header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Your posted data is typically is a string formatted like this:

```
field=bletch&jackwagon=hungrypants
```

...but it doesn't have to be..

My guess is you are missing the header for form data:  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Check out this post

[Reading FromUri and FromBody at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072277/reading-fromuri-and-frombody-at-the-same-time)