# Upload in Webapi ASP.NET Core json vs formdata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, upload

I'm using **webapi asp.net core**, initially my actions were using the **[FromBody]** attribute on the parameters, and my front end send a json. Now I'm implementing a screen that has **upload**, and I had to use FormData to send the file, and at that point I inserted my object (which I used to send as json) in my **FormData**. So, I needed to change my backend to accept the FormData, just remove [FromBody].

I would like use my action, both by passing formdata or passing a json, is it possible? How can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

```
YourController{
public IHttpActionResult YourMethod([FromBody] model1, [FromForm]model2)
{
//your model1 defines json model.
//model2  defines properties for file
}
}
```

[Something Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072277/reading-fromuri-and-frombody-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Not work with me. I get the error "Unsupported Media Type".

Comment: Please look at this post. Apparently this guy is doing same thing as what you want to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api