# Error while calling Webapi in my asp.net project

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is my api code that return successfull json data while using get method

```
public Question[] Get() {
    getQuestion obj = new AllDataAccess.getQuestion();
    return obj.questionList().ToArray();
}
```

This is my post method data that accept the value and save in database

```
public void Post([FromBody] string question) {
    SaveQuestion obj = new AllDataAccess.controller.SaveQuestion();
    obj.savaData(question);
}
```

This is the method that call my  api

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:53893/api/values',
    data: "{'question':'" + $("#submit").value + "'}",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data, status) {    
        console.log(status);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Now the problem is when i post the data with one textbox value its give me a message in console that "nocontent" and record save in data base with null value

Comment: Do not build JSON like that. If a user enters `'` in the text field, they have immediately broken it.

Comment: then how can i save my value because it's show me only null value

Comment: On the JS side you should use `JSON.stringify(model)` and on the server side, you need to define a model rather than using [string with FromBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853188/frombody-string-parameter-is-giving-null).

Comment: As a side note, `async: false` is deprecated and should never be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your ajax url is wrong. You should specify the action name `(post)`. Also, use `JSON.stringify` to retrieve proper json from javascript object.

```
    var postData = { question:$("#submit").val() };
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: 'http://localhost:53893/api/values/post',
       data: JSON.stringify(postData),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data,status) {
           console.log(status);
       },
       error: function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
    });
```

In the server side, you should create a model class for `Post` method;

```
public class PostInput
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
}
```

And then `Post` method looks like;

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]PostInput input)
{
     SaveQuestion obj = new AllDataAccess.controller.SaveQuestion();
     obj.savaData(question);
}
```

Comment: And he's also trying to use `[FromBody] string` rather than using a model.

Comment: @vaibhav Perhaps you're missing the `[HttpPost]` method on the model?

Comment: @vaibhav, as john said, you should add the [HttpPost] attribute on the method.

Comment: `$("#submit").value` is probably `undefined` btw... I guess OP wants `$("#submit").val()`

Comment: i correct my value mistake to val and i also define [httpost] but i still get error of 405

Comment: and how can i define model in function parameter ?

Comment: @vaibhav, are you add HttpPost attribute for Post method ?

Comment: Would you try to use "JSON.stringify". I updated the answer.

Comment: it is giving me an error  like this  "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: Better use a HttpGet and append the querystring as we are not using a complex type. Just a thought :)

Comment: thank you so much all of you and special @rainman its worked for me by adding json.stringnify thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `FromBody`, you can do so.
JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //default content-type, could be omitted
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    url: 'http://localhost:53893/api/values/post',
    data: {'': $("#submit").val()}
});
```

API action

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string question)
{
     SaveQuestion obj = new AllDataAccess.controller.SaveQuestion();
     obj.savaData(question);
}
```

You had these issues.

1. Wrong `content-type` for your ajax call.
2. Data was not posted correctly.
3. `val()` should be used instead of `.value`.
4. API action should be decorated with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: @Rainman: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12072419/17447 this is what I understand too